# How to move table data from one environment to another environment in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, toad

I am a novice Oracle User.
I want to move a table records from QA to Test environment. The table already exists in  Test. Would it be something like this ?

```
insert into wKTest01.MyTableIWantToMove select * from wkQA01.MyTableIWantToMove ;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Both the tables in both environments have same number of columns with same data types.

Comment: What do you mean by "environment"?  Are these two different schemas in the same database?  Or are they two different databases?  Normally, different environments would be different databases (generally on different servers) in which case you would need a database link.  Less commonly, you mean mean that you have different schemas in the same database in which case the statement you posted would work (assuming that the order of columns in the tables match as well as the number of columns and their data types).

Comment: @JustinCave I meant two different databases and same schema.

Answer (score 1):

You can use database links in Oracle to do this.Create a database link in your test database called myQADBLink which points to your QA DB.

The code would look something like this

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK myQADBLink CONNECT TO <username> identified by
<password> USING
'<QA DBconnect string>';

SELECT 1 FROM dual@myQADBLink; -- This is to test if your dblink is created properly.
```

Now you can copy from QA to test by saying

```
INSERT INTO wKTest01.MyTableIWantToMove select * from wkQA01.MyTableIWantToMove@myQADBLink;
```

Comment: I had a question. What would come under QA DBconnect string ? Would it have the QA database name ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it actually exists, right like you put it.

Here is the full syntax guide for this: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/insert-select.html.

Later, when you might place your tables at the different Oracle instances, google 'Orace DBLink' for the good ;)